# How to print specific key in an array (Perl)

Tags: perl

I recently started learning Perl, so I'm not too familiar with the functions and syntax.
If I have a Perl array and some variables,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @numbers = (a =>1, b=> 2, c => 3, d =>4, e => 5);
my $x;
my $range = 5;
$x = int(rand($range));
print "$x";
```

to generate a random number between 1-5, how can I get the program to print the actual key (a, b, c, etc.) instead of just the number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

Comment: rand(5) will return a number from 0 to 4.9999...; int makes it an integer from 0-4

Comment: This might be a helpful resource: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html

Comment: The keys (indexes) of `@numbers` are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`. `a`, `b` and `c` aren't even valid keys (indexes) for an array.

Comment: Why not using `qw(a b c d e)[int(rand(5))]`? Items in an array have an index already; if you want an individual index, you might want to use a hash instead: `{1=> 'a', 2=> 'b', 3 => 'c', 4 => 'd', 5 => 'e'}->{int(1 + rand(5))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to do a reverse lookup, key-by-value, opposite to what we get from a hash.  Since a hash is a list you can [reverse](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) it and use the resulting hash to look up by number.

A couple of corrections: you need a [hash variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Hashes) (not an array), and you need to add `1` to your [rand](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) integer generator so to have the desired `1..5` range

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %numbers = (a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5);

my %lookup_by_number = reverse %numbers;  # values need be unique

my $range = 5;
my $x = int(rand $range) + 1;

say $lookup_by_number{$x};
```

Without reversing the hash you'd need to iterate the hash `%numbers` over [values](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html), testing each against `$x` so to find its key.

If there are same values for various keys in your original hash then you have to do it by hand since `reverse`-ing would attempt to create a hash with duplicate keys, in which case only the last one assigned remains. So you'd lose some values. One way

```
my @at_num = grep { $x == $numbers{$_} } keys %numbers;
```

as in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221463/simple-hash-search-by-value) that this was marked as duplicate of.

---

But then you should build a data structure for reverse lookup so to not search through the list every time information is needed. This can be a hash where keys are the list of unique numbers while their values are then array references (*arrayrefs*) with corresponding keys from the original hash

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %num = (a => 1, b => 2, c => 1, d => 3, e => 2);  # with duplicate values

my %lookup_by_num;

foreach my $key (keys %num) {
    push @{ $lookup_by_num{$num{$key}} }, $key;
}

say "$_ => [ @{$lookup_by_num{$_}} ]" for keys %lookup_by_num;
```

This prints

```
1 => [ c a ]
3 => [ d ]
2 => [ e b ]
```

A nice way to display complex data structures is via [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), or [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) (or others).

The expression `@{ $lookup_by_num{ $num{$key} } }` extracts the value of `%lookup_by_num` for the key `$num{$key}`and dereferences it `@{ ... }`, so that it can then `push` the `$key` to it.  The critical part of this is that the first time it  encounters `$num{$key}` it *autovivifies* the arrayref and its corresponding key.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872658/4653379) with its references for details.

Comment: @Slippy I added discussion of a more complex case, when values of some keys are the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do it.  For example, declare "numbers" as a hash rather than an array.  Note that the keys come first in each key-value pair, and here you want to use your random int as the key:

```
my %numbers = ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd', 4 => 'e' );
```

Then you can look up the "key" as you call it using:

```
my $key = $numbers{$x};
```

Note that [`rand( $x );`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) returns a number greater than or equal to zero and *less than $x*.  So if you want integers in the range 1-5, you must add 1 in your code: at the moment you'll get 0-4, not 1-5.

Comment: It's not working for me when I try your code.
Do I need to convert the hash into an array first?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, arrays don't have keys (well, they kind of do, but they're integers and not the values you want). So I think you want a hash, not an array.

```
my %numbers = (a =>1, b=> 2, c => 3, d =>4, e => 5);
```

And if you want to get the letter, given the integer then you need the reverse of this hash:

```
my %rev_numbers = %numbers;
```

Note that reversing a hash like this only works if the values in your original hash are unique (because reversing a hash makes the values into keys and hash keys are always unique).

Then, you can just look up an integer in your `%rev_hash` to get its associated letter.

```
my $integer = 3;
say $rev_numbers{$integer}; # prints 'c'
```